# How do you stop and reset a form before it submits data to a database

Tags: vb.net

I am making a login page and I have done the registration form, however, I need to validate the username. I have done the validating part, however, I can't seem to get it to not submit the data and reset the username box. This is the code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Public Class Register

```
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Private Sub rB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rB.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\Visual Studio 2015/users.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim usf As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [users] WHERE [username] = '" & uT.Text, myConnection)
    Dim userFound As Boolean = True
    If userFound = True Then
        MsgBox("Username already found; Please choose another")
        Dim frm = New Register
        frm.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If

    Dim str As String
    str = "insert into users ([username], [password], [Firstname], [LastName]) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("username", CType(uT.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("password", CType(pT.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("FirstName", CType(fnT.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LastName", CType(lnT.Text, String)))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        uT.Clear()
        pT.Clear()
        fnT.Clear()
        lnT.Clear()
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code, not an image of your code.

Comment: `making a login page` you might want to add the tag for the project type too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please post your code instead of including an image as it's hard to reference back to when describing problems found.

That being said. You have a boolean UserFound that you are declaring and setting to True and then immediately checking to see if it's true. Of course it's going to be true, you just set it.

Also, I see nowhere in that image where you're even passing the query to get results back. (ie, executeReader, executeScalar)

Typically you can query the database and then check to see if any rows were returned or use executeScalar against a single column to see if a value was returned.

Comment: So you need to instantiate a reader and execute it and if any rows were returned react accordingly